# APK instala porem não executa - IONIC

Tags: linux, ionic, ionic2, apk

Estou tendo a seguinte dificuldade a alguns dias, após gerar a minha APK e instalar no meu dispositivo ao tentar abrir ele apresenta a mensagem

> o app parou

Peguei um projeto antigo feito em ionic e adicionei novas funcionalidades nele, quando executo os comandos para adicionar a plataforma: `ionic cordova platform add android` e gerar a apk: `ionic cordova build android`, ele funciona normalmente e gera a minha APK.

Porem quando pego a APK gerada e instalo em meu celular e tento abrir aparace a mensagem `O app parou` e se fecho e tento abrir novamente ele apresenta a mensagem `O app apresenta erros continuamente`.

Porem se executo no navegador ele funciona normalmente.

Características do meu ambiente

> **S.O.** : Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
>
> **Ionic:**
>     ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1
>
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
>
> @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
>
> **Cordova:**
>     cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
>
> Cordova Platforms     : android 6.3.0
>
> Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (23 plugins total)
>
> **System:**
>     Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
>
> NodeJS            : v8.12.0
>
> npm               : 6.4.1
>
> OS                : Linux 4.15

Comment: O sistema operacional esta dizendo: O app apresenta erros. Não tem alternativa, você vai ter de investigar o(s) motivo(s) do(s) erro(s).

Comment: Habilite a depuração USB e execute o monitor (android sdk/tools) para saber o que está interrompendo a execução.

Comment: Provavelmente é algum plugin que não tem suporte a versão do seu android. Já passei por isso com o plugin background.

Comment: @GuilhermeLirio não tenho esse plugin em meu projeto. Teve alguma outra coisa que você fez para solucionar esse problema?

Comment: Teste o comando: cordova serve, e abre o endereço que ele solicita (localhosr:8000). Clica em browser e veja se há algum erro de JS.